# The meaning of 激ギレ

Tags: words, meaning

> SMAP香取、フット岩尾に激ギレされた

What does 激ギレ mean?

It is not on ALC and Google has nothing for 激ギレとは.
Is it a particular form of frustration/angriness? Does it always have to include the act of venting out, or can it be 100% inside the head with no externally visible behavior modification?

Comment: This is the first time I saw the verb vent was used in a figurative way. That said, I guess 激ギレ is a slang for "fury", "rage", So probably the action included extremely emotional behaviours.

Comment: See also: [zokugo-dict entry for 「激～」](http://zokugo-dict.com/09ke/geki.htm).

Answer (score 2):

It's `激` for `激しい・非常に` and the `ギレ` comes from `切れる・キレる`, so it means "to snap", "to lose one's temper" in an extensive manner. 
Maybe you could say "to freak out" in terms of anger. Because it's `激`, you're good to think of an externally visible behavior.